# Writing an sql query that uses count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

Im trying to write a query that utilizes count in sql. The query I am trying to write is.

```
Find users that reviewed at least 2 restaurants.
```

Here are the tables that I am using:

```
explain is_a_restaurant;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| business_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| cuisine_type | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total_seats  | int(11)     | YES  |     | 1       |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


explain reviews;
 +-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 
 | Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | business_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | user_id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | review_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | review_date | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | star_rating | int(1)  | YES  |     | 1       |       |
 +-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+


 explain users;
 +------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | user_id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | name       | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | user_since | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

Here is what ive tried (ive tried a lot more than this but heres one):

```
SELECT reviews.user_id FROM reviews JOIN is_a_restaurant ON 
(reviews.business_id = is_a_restaurant) WHERE (count(*).is_a_restaurant > 1) 
GROUP BY reviews.user_id ASC;
```

Heres the error that I get

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near '.is_a_restaurant > 1) GROUP BY reviews.user_id ASC' at line 1
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: "reviews.business_id = is_a_restaurant"?

Comment: calm down idk why i didnt write .business_id after that lawlrus

Comment: @BobblyFillay If it is just a typo, I'd recommend editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a MySQL guy so my syntax might be a little out, but you probably want to using a HAVING clause.

```
SELECT reviews.user_id 
FROM reviews 
JOIN is_a_restaurant ON reviews.business_id = is_a_restaurant.business_id
GROUP BY reviews.user_id ASC
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The HAVING clause is like a WHERE clause but is used for aggregated values (the COUNT in this case).

You were also missing the column name from is_a_restaurant in the JOIN expression.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) clause.

```
SELECT reviews.user_id 
FROM reviews
JOIN is_a_restaurant ON (reviews.business_id = is_a_restaurant.business_id)
GROUP BY reviews.user_id ASC
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

count() is an aggregate function. SQL aggregate functions are those which return a single value, calculated from values in a column.You can not use where clause with aggregate functions.Instead,you have to use having clause.
Below are the most commonly used aggregate functions.

1. AVG() - Returns the average value
2. COUNT() - Returns the number of rows
3. FIRST() - Returns the first value
4. LAST() - Returns the last value
5. MAX() - Returns the largest value
6. MIN() - Returns the smallest value
7. SUM() - Returns the sum

So,use having instead of where.
Take care and good luck....!!